# Como trazer somente resultados dos últimos 30 minutos

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma tabela no sqlserver que serão registrados logs de erros no qual contem os seguintes campos:

sequência \ data \ mensagem

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar os resultados dos últimos 30 minutos de acordo com a data atual que rodar o job exemplo:

data: `08/10/2014 10:00`
     `10:08/2014 09:30`

Supondo que o job rodará às 10:30 ele deverá trazer somente o erro ocorrido às 10:00

Como posso montar uma query para obter esse resultado.

Observação: já consegui montar o código que colocará esse registro em uma tabela só preciso mesmo extrair os registros dos últimos 30 minutos a cada vez que for executado.

Comment: use functions como DATEADD E GETDATE  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258863%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: Muito obrigado Motta, perfeita a sua explicação e solução.

Comment: Não, o Omni que deu a solução eu só indiquei a fonte.

Comment: @Motta colocamos ao mesmo tempo. Vou editar a resposta e colocar o teu link para quem quiser aprofundar o conhecimento sobre essas funções.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando [`DATEADD()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
select dateadd(minute, -30, getdate())
```

Logo no seu caso a sua query ficara algo como:

```
select *
from tabela
where data >= dateadd(minute, -30, getdate())
```

Exemplo no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c650/1)

EDIT:

Mais informações sobre as funções que lidam com datas e tempo em T-SQL [aqui](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258863%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

(Obrigado [Motta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5005/motta) pelo link).